# Can you connect Views to eventhandlers using XML?

Tags: android, xml, events, event-handling

Sometimes you want to start an Activity by pressing a Button.

Is there a way to express that in XML?  I.e. to tag the Button xml with the Activity to render when it is clicked?  That would certainly be a lot quicker and slicker and shorter than writing the equivalent Java code to handle the event.

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xml you can only set name of method that will be started on click event (same as setOncClickListener ) using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

But it's not possible to define exactly what will be done after button click.